# Probability that a $n$-dimensional Gaussian falls into a half-space

Tags: convex-analysis, normal-distribution, convex-optimization, polyhedra

For $a \in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}^d$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$, we can define a half-space as the set of points $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ such that $a \cdot x \le b$, namely,

$$\mathcal{H}(a,b) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^d \mid a \cdot x \le b\}.$$

Fix $\mu \in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}^d$.  Let $X$ be a random variable on $\mathbb{R}^d$ with a Gaussian distribution, in particular, with the following distribution: $X=(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_d)$ where $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_d$ are mutually independent and $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i,1)$ (i.e., $X_i$ has a Gaussian distribution with mean $\mu_i$ and variance $1$).

We can define a function $f:\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}^{d+1} \to \mathbb{R}$ as

$$f(a,b) = \Pr[X \in \mathcal{H}(a,b)].$$

Of course, $f$ implicitly depends on $\mu$.

My question: is $f$ convex/concave?  Does it have at most one local maximum on closed, convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}^{d+1}$?  If not, does it have any other nice properties that would make it easy to computationally find a maximum of $f$, given $\mu$?

---

(This arose while examining an application, explained here: [Approximating a convex polyhedron, with fewer inequalities](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/20217/5038).)

Comment: The random variable $a\cdot X$ is itself a Gaussian, with mean $a \cdot \mu$ and variance $\sum a_i^2$.  So $f(a,b)$ can be given explicitly in terms of $\text{erf}\left((a\cdot \mu - b) / \sqrt{\sum a_i^2}\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ does not have a maximum. You can take a sequence of $(a_k,b_k)$ such that $f(a_k,b_k)\to 1$ while $f(a,b)<1$ for all $a,b$.